# Determine a range (interval) of integer values in an arrayList

Tags: java, range, intervals

I want to develop a function which works as a filter through a set of integers in an arrayList. Basically I will have to retrieve the max and min values in an arrayList.

Example: min= 1970 AND max=2012 (talking about years, but they are treated as simple integers)

I have to determine a range of five-years, so that the output would be

"From 1970 to 1975" onclick I will have the list "1970","1971","1972","1973", "1974","1975"
"From 1970 to 1975".......
......
"From 2010 to 2012" onclick I will have the list "2010","2011", "2012"

I have previously used pattern/matcher in order to create intervals alphabetically, where I would classify strings in the right alphabetical range (ex. from A to B) but this is different since I have to define a range of 5, and create subarrays.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "onclic"?

Comment: By 'onclic' are you referring to some event? Also please elaborate a little more. Code snippets, if you have tried something, would help.

Answer (score -1):

Providing the list is sorted then you can just have a simple function which gets the index of the lower value, the index of the higher value - and then returns a sublist using those indexes.

Here is an example program:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 1970; i < 2013; i++) {
            myList.add(i);
        }

        List<Integer> subList = getRange(myList, 1988, 1994);

        for (Integer i : subList) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    public static List<Integer> getRange(List<Integer> fromList, int lowVal, int highVal)
    {
        int lowValIndex = fromList.indexOf(lowVal);
        int highValIndex = fromList.indexOf(highVal);

        return fromList.subList(lowValIndex, highValIndex + 1); 
    }

}
```

This will return 1988 -> 1994 from the list.